# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \sqrt[n]{a} \right) \cos \left( n \pi +{\pi \over 6} \right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to conclude about the convergence of

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \sqrt[n]{a} \right) \cos \left( n \pi +{\pi \over 6} \right)$$
where $a>0$. Do you have any clues?

Comment: $\cos\left(n\pi+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=(-1)^n\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ simplifies things. Now what can you say about the convergence of $\sqrt[n]{a}$ for positive values of $a$?

Comment: Try to use limit test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the absolute value of the general term of the series, one has
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\left( \sqrt[n]{a} \right) \cos \left( n \pi +{\pi \over 6} \right)\right|=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|(-1)^n\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}a^{1/n}\right|=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cdot 1\neq0,
$$ then the given series is *divergent*.

Comment: You have now shown the series is not absolutely convergent, but that doesn't mean the original series diverges. It could still be conditionally convergent, right?

Comment: @DennisvandenBerg No. I've shown that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left( \sqrt[n]{a} \right) \cos \left( n \pi +{\pi \over 6} \right)\neq 0$, then the *general term* of the series doesn't tend to $0$, the series can't converge.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Thanks for taking the time to write this down. I have one question. If we modify the original problem to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \sqrt[n]{a}-1 \right) \cos \left( n \pi +{\pi \over 6} \right)$ then we would get convergence from the Leibniz criterion?

Comment: @Zelazny In this case one may notice that, as $n \to \infty$, $\left( \sqrt[n]{a}-1 \right)=e^{\frac{\ln a}{n}}-1=\frac{\ln a}{n}+O(\frac{1}{n^2})$ and the new series is *convergent* being the sum of $\frac{\sqrt{3}\ln a}{2} \sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ and $\sum O(\frac{1}{n^2})$, two *convergent* series. Hope this helps you.